# Determinant of a matrix involving the Prolate Spheroidal Wave Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory, signal-analysis

The Prolate Spheroidal Wave Functions are eigenfunctions of the following integral equation:
$$\int_{-T}^T\varphi_n(x) \text{sinc}(t-x) dx = \lambda_n \varphi_n(t)$$

where $\text{sinc}(t) = \sin(\pi t)/ \pi t$. Alternatively (as discovered by Slepian et al.) they are also the eigenfunctions of the following differential operator:
$$(1-t^2)\frac{d^2\varphi_n}{dt^2}-2t\frac{d\varphi_n}{dt} -(2 \pi T \Omega)^2t^2 \varphi_n = \mu_n \varphi_n$$

What I would like to prove is that the following $p \times p$ matrix-valued function:
$$ \mathbf{S}_{i, k}(u) = \sum_{r = 0}^{R-1}\varphi_r\left(\frac{T}{\Omega}\left(u+\frac{i}{p}\right)\right)\varphi_r\left(\frac{T}{\Omega}\left(u+\frac{k}{p}\right)\right) i,k = 0,\ldots,p-1$$
defined for $u \in [0, 1/p)$ has a positive determinant $a.e.$ on $[0,1/p)$ i.e.,

$$ \text{det}(\mathbf{S}(u)) = K > 0 \text{ } a.e. \text{ } on \text{ } [0, 1/p) $$

The condition on $R$ (the number of prolates to be summed) is $R \geq 2 \pi \Omega T$ where $2 \pi \Omega T $ is the so-called "time-bandwidth product".

As an alternative (though difficult but equivalent) task one may prove that for:
$$\lambda_{max}(\mathbf{S}) = \underset{u \in [0, 1/p)}{\mathrm{ess \  sup}} \ \underset{1\leq i \leq p}{\ \mathrm{max}\ } \lambda_i (\mathbf{S})(u)$$
and
$$\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{S}) = \underset{u \in [0, 1/p)}{\mathrm{ess \  inf}} \ \underset{1\leq i \leq p}{\ \mathrm{min}\ } \lambda_i (\mathbf{S})(u)$$

we have $0< \lambda_{min}(\mathbf{S}) \leq \lambda_{max}(\mathbf{S}) < \infty$

I have performed numerical experiments and there seems to be ample evidence that the determinant is indeed positive. I have surveyed a lot of literature on the Prolates, but have not been able to make any progress. Any pointers/hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked for some time on the problem and made some progress. The argument is basically inductive. First all I would like to tell that this problem arises in Gabor Theory if one wants to prove that a Gabor frame can be generated by multiple prolate spheroidal wave functions i.e. if one wants to prove that the sequence
$${e^{2 \pi i m b} \varphi_r(t-n a): m, n, r \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq r \leq R-1}$$
forms a ["frame"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra)) (using what is known as the [Zak Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zak_transform)). 
So far this has not been done in the literature on prolates or Gabor theory.

The key is to take into consideration the well-known fact that the prolates form a Complete Chebyshev system on the interval $[-1, 1]$. So (assuming $T$ and $\Omega$ are both 1) the following determinant is non-zero:
$$ \Delta
  \left( {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \varphi_0 &  \varphi_1 & \cdots & \varphi_r\\
   x_0 & x_1 & \cdots & x_r\\
  \end{array} } \right)= \mathrm{det}(\varphi_i(x_j))_{i,j=0}^{n}, \text{ }\forall r \in \mathbb{Z_+}, 0 \leq x_0< x_1 <\cdots< x_r \leq 1.
$$

Writing out explicitly, the condition is given as:
$$\left| \begin{array}{cccc}
   \varphi_0(x_0) &  \varphi_0(x_1) & \cdots & \varphi_0(x_r)\\
   \varphi_1(x_0) &  \varphi_1(x_1) & \cdots & \varphi_1(x_r)\\
   \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
   \varphi_r(x_0) &  \varphi_r(x_1) & \cdots & \varphi_r(x_r)\\
  \end{array} \right| \neq 0$$
for any finite set $\{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_r\} \subseteq [0,1]$.

I will give the simple argument for $p=2$ and $R \geq p$. I have even done it for $p=3$ but I need an elegant inductive argument for all $p$. Introduce the slight abuse of notation:
$$
\varphi_r(i) \equiv \varphi_r\left(u+\frac{i}{p}\right), \text{ } i=0,1,\ldots, p-1
$$

For $R=2$ and $p=2$, $\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{S})$ reads:
$$\left| \begin{array}{cccc}
\varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(0)+\varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(0) &  \varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(1)+\varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(1)\\
\varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(0)+\varphi_1(1)\varphi_1(0) &  \varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(1)+\varphi_1(1)\varphi_1(1)\\
  \end{array} \right|$$
This deteminant can be decomposed into four determinants as
$$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
\varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(0) & \varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(1) \\
\varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(0) & \varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(1)
\end{array}\right| + \left| \begin{array}{cc}
\varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(0) & \varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(1) \\
\varphi_1(1)\varphi_1(0) & \varphi_0(1)\varphi_1(1)
\end{array}\right| + \left| \begin{array}{cc}
\varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(0) & \varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(1) \\
\varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(0) & \varphi_1(1)\varphi_1(1)
\end{array}\right| + \left| \begin{array}{cc}
\varphi_1(0)\varphi_1(0) & \varphi_0(0)\varphi_0(1) \\
\varphi_1(1)\varphi_1(0) & \varphi_0(1)\varphi_0(1)
\end{array}\right|$$

The first two determinants are easily seen to be zero, while the sum of the last two determinants is equal to (after taking out common factors in entries in a given column):
$$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
\varphi_0(0) & \varphi_0(1) \\
\varphi_1(0) & \varphi_1(1)
\end{array}\right|^2$$

Which is positive by the Chebyshev assumption. An inductive argument can be invoked for $R>2$. What I would request is a general inductive argument for all $p$, i.e., assuming $\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{S}) > 0$ for all $R \geq p=2$ and for a certain $p>2$ prove the proposition for $p+1$.

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem by using the Cauchy-Binnet formula for the determinant of the product of two rectangular matrices